# spark with Hadoop 2.3.0 on Mesos 0.21.0 with error "sh: 1: hadoop: not found" on slave

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mesos

I am setting up for spark with Hadoop 2.3.0 on Mesos 0.21.0. when I try spark on the master, I get these error messages fro stderr of mesos slave:

> WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
>
> I1229 12:34:45.923665  8571 fetcher.cpp:76] Fetching URI
>   'hdfs://10.170.207.41/spark/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz'
>
> I1229 12:34:45.925240  8571 fetcher.cpp:105] Downloading resource from
>   'hdfs://10.170.207.41/spark/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz' to
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141226-161203-701475338-5050-6942-S0/frameworks/20141229-111020-701475338-5050-985-0001/executors/20141226-161203-701475338-5050-6942-S0/runs/8ef30e72-d8cf-4218-8a62-bccdf673b5aa/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz'
>
> E1229 12:34:45.927089  8571 fetcher.cpp:109] HDFS copyToLocal failed:
>   hadoop fs -copyToLocal 'hdfs://10.170.207.41/spark/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz'
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141226-161203-701475338-5050-6942-S0/frameworks/20141229-111020-701475338-5050-985-0001/executors/20141226-161203-701475338-5050-6942-S0/runs/8ef30e72-d8cf-4218-8a62-bccdf673b5aa/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz'
>
> sh: 1: hadoop: not found
>
> Failed to fetch: hdfs://10.170.207.41/spark/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz
>
> Failed to synchronize with slave (it's probably exited)

The interesting thing is that when i switch to the slave node and run the same command

> hadoop fs -copyToLocal 'hdfs://10.170.207.41/spark/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz'
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141226-161203-701475338-5050-6942-S0/frameworks/20141229-111020-701475338-5050-985-0001/executors/20141226-161203-701475338-5050-6942-S0/runs/8ef30e72-d8cf-4218-8a62-bccdf673b5aa/spark-1.2.0.tar.gz'

, it goes well.

Comment: I've checked the thread [Hadoop 2.5.0 on Mesos 0.21.0 with library 0.0.8 executor error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254666/hadoop-2-5-0-on-mesos-0-21-0-with-library-0-0-8-executor-error), which can not solve my problem

Comment: What user is mesos-slave run as? Does that user have `hadoop` in their PATH, and execute permission?

Comment: it's root, and have hadoop in its PATH

Comment: (And root has execute permission on the actual hadoop binary?)

Comment: I had the same error in logs.  It turned out that I had forgotten to restart a slave that did not have HADOOP_HOME set or hadoop on the path.  Once I restarted the master and slave, mesos found hadoop.

Comment: Thanks, @jlb. it is strange that if start mesos-slave by command line with specifying HADOOP_HOME, it works. However, if i start mesos-slave by service command, it will get the error i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When starting mesos slave, you have to specify the path to your hadoop installation through the following parameter:

```
--hadoop_home=/path/to/hadoop
```

Without that it just didn't work for me, even though I had the HADOOP_HOME environment variable set up.